# Assign value from getDirectory after click on Button using jython

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I'm trying to write a simple GUI to enter some data to an Imagej plugin using jython.

Some of the data to be entered are two directories (input and output) after clicking on two respective buttons. The problem I have is that I don't know how to assign a particular value obtained by getDirectory to a variable. If I set the variable "out" (within the class MyListener) as global I can use it but that way I can only use it only once as the second time it will erase the first directory.

The question would be how to make the class "MyListener" to return the chosen directory and set that to a particular variable.

The Generic Dialog code is the following:

```python
from ij.gui import GenericDialog, DialogListener
from ij.io import DirectoryChooser
from java.awt import Button
from java.awt.event import ActionListener, ActionEvent
from ij.plugin.frame.Editor import actionPerformed


class MyListener (ActionListener):
    def actionPerformed(self, event):
        out = DirectoryChooser("Choose!!").getDirectory()
        return out

def getOptions():

    bt01 = Button("Get Directory")
    bt02 = Button("Get Directory")

    bt01.addActionListener(MyListener())
    bt02.addActionListener(MyListener())

    gd = GenericDialog("Directories")
    gd.addStringField("FA Name", "File name")
    gd.add(bt01)
    gd.add(bt02)
    gd.showDialog()  

    if gd.wasCanceled():  
        print "User canceled. Exiting...."  
        return

    return bt01, bt02

options = getOptions()  
if options is not None:  
    dir01, dir02 = options 

    print dir01, dir02'
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getDirectory()` helper function in the [`ij.IJ`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/IJ.html) class:

```python
from ij import IJ
from ij.gui import GenericDialog

def getOptions():

    dir1 = IJ.getDirectory("Choose first directory")
    dir2 = IJ.getDirectory("Choose second directory")

    gd = GenericDialog("Directories")
    gd.addStringField("FA Name", "File name")
    gd.showDialog()  

    if gd.wasCanceled():  
        print "User canceled. Exiting...."  
        return
    fileName = gd.getNextString()
    return dir1, dir2, fileName

options = getOptions() 
if options is not None:
    dir01, dir02, name = options 

    print dir01, dir02, name
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid the sequential popping up of dialogs and prefer a single dialog with all the options, you can use [`GenericDialogPlus`](http://fiji.sc/javadoc/index.html?fiji/util/gui/GenericDialogPlus.html) within Fiji. This class provides an `addDirectoryField(String label, String defaultPath)` method.